# Mapping x2: Using threads to do work

Tags: .net, f#

Attempting to do some asynchronous programming via threads.  To start with, I am trying a simple case: mapping a list in parallel.  The code so far looks like:

```
let doWork (x:('a -> string)) (y:'a) (z:string ref) (finished:bool ref) =
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( fun _ -> z:= x y
                                           finished:= true)
let dualmap (x:'a list) (y:'a -> string) (z:string -> 'b) = 
    let acc = []
    let rec dual (x:'a list) (y:'a -> 'b) (acc:'b list) = 
            match x with
            | [] -> acc
            | [i] -> (y i)::acc
            | i::j::tl -> let un      = ref ""
                          let deux    = ref ""
                          let unfin   = ref false
                          let deuxfin = ref false
                          doWork y i un   unfin   |> ignore //case i
                          doWork y j deux deuxfin |> ignore //case j
                          while not(unfin)||not(deuxfin) do Thread.Sleep(0)
                          let uno  = z !un
                          let dos  = z !deux 
                          dual tl y (dos::(uno::acc))
    dual x y acc
```

However, I am not sure how to get the threads to do work, since they seem to be `obj -> unit` rather than `'a -> 'b` or `'a -> 'b -> 'c`, which is what I would need.

Instead, I have to make sure I know how to convert every object I hve into a string, and then convert it back.  It seems like there must be an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wanting to do something like this?

```
let asyncMap f items = 
  let rec loop acc items =
    async {
      match items with
      | [] -> return List.rev acc
      | [x] -> 
        let! a = f x
        return! loop (a::acc) []
      | x::y::rest ->
        let! a = f x
        let! b = f y
        return! loop (b::a::acc) rest
    }
  loop [] items
```

Comment: yeah; except more like ssh than gridengine (ssh being the equivalent of grabbing a host on a cluster--or a thread from a threadpool--and gridengine being the equivalent of async, except on a bunch of random hosts instead of threads)

anyhow, ill give it a try

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use `StartChild` to run things in parallel so that you can return values with static types?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370511.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the low-level `Thread` API (which is tedious and error prone); use either the Task Parallel Library (classes in `System.Threading.Tasks`) or PLINQ (the classes in `System.Linq` that have `Parallel` in their names).  Here's an example of the latter:

```
open System.Linq

let pmap (x:_ seq) (f:'a -> 'b) =
    x.AsParallel().AsOrdered().Select(f).AsEnumerable()
```

Comment: I really need to play with the TPL.